# Python Popen.waitpid returns "[Errno 10] No child processes"

Tags: python, linux, process, fork

I have a working Python script that executes an external command and calls `Popen.communicate()`. However when I call this script from a C process, it fails in `os.waitpid()` with "[Errno 10] No child processes". *Why?*

This looks like [a certain bug in Python](http://bugs.python.org/issue1731717), but I'm not using threads.

The C process forks, changes its UID, GID, and calls `setsid()` and then `execle()` (with "/bin/sh -c /python/script").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in my case was that the C process was ignoring `SIGCHLD`. Since ignored signals are inherited by a forked process, Python process was ignoring it as well, which made `waitpid()` fail.

**Solution:** set signal handlers in the C process after forking to `SIG_DFL`, if you've ignored any.